# Scala error Expression of type subtype doesn't conform to expected type T

Tags: scala, generics, inheritance

This piece of code does not compile, I'm getting the following errors:
*Expression of type MessageA doesn't conform to expected type T*
*Expression of type MessageB doesn't conform to expected type T*

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._

abstract class BaseMessage

case class MessageA(x : String = "aaa") extends BaseMessage

case class MessageB(y : String = "bbbb") extends BaseMessage

val TypeA = typeTag[MessageA]
val TypeB = typeTag[MessageB]

def decode[T <: BaseMessage](xml: String)(implicit tag: TypeTag[T]): T = {
  tag match {
    case TypeA => MessageA()
    case TypeB => MessageB()
  }
}
```

Essentially I want to decode some xml string and return the corresponding message.

I got this to work though

```
def decode[T <: BaseMessage](xml: String)(implicit tag: TypeTag[T]): BaseMessage = {
  tag match {
    case TypeA => MessageA()
    case TypeB => MessageB()
  }
}
```

The above is returning `BaseMessage` instead of `T` and I'm having to cast at the call site. How do I get the decode function to return T? I'd like to be able to do the following

```
val a: MessageA = decode[MessageA]("xml...")
val b: MessageB = decode[MessageB]("xml...")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the typetag is probably a distraction and not needed. Perhaps you could create your own typeclass that does the actual work needed to create each of these instances. For instance:

```
trait Decoder[T <: BaseMessage] {
  def decode(xml: String): T
}

implicit val messageADecoder = new Decoder[MessageA] {
  def decode(xml: String): MessageA = MessageA()
}
// same for MessageB and other classes...

def decode[T <: BaseMessage](xml: String)(implicit dec: Decoder[T]): T = {
  dec.decode(xml)
}
```

Comment: This works when I call it this way `val a: MessageA = decode("xml")(messageADecoder)` but that means that I'm having to expose the decoders to the caller. Since the models (e.g. MessageA, MessageB) are already exposed to the caller, is there an easy way I can call the method like this `val a: MessageA = decode[MessageA]("xml...")` instead?